# How to restrict class usage

Tags: asp.net, .net, class, restriction

Is there a way to enforce a class only to be used in ASP.NET ? So that it can't be referenced in a WinForm app or throw exception when instantiated. Is there some kind of .NET class attribute for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't!!!**

```
public class WebOnly
{
    public WebOnly()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            throw new Exception("me needs web");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `internal` access modifier allows classes/methods to only be used within the same assembly.

As long as the deployment of the application / web application is set up so that the class you wish to protect is in a separate assembly to the web application, the class will not be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Aspect Oriented Programming techniques.

[PostSharp's](https://www.postsharp.net/architecture) solution:

Control object visibility – Sometimes internal and private keywords are not enough. Restrict which namespace, assembly or type can reference a member or implement an interface.